# How to create a new process in C++ code under Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, process

Can anybody answer me the question of how to create a new process from within C++ code with specific parameters for that process under windows ?
e.g how to execute

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe"

with some arguments ?
or
how to execute "reg import myRegEntry.reg" ?

I like explanations, but sometimes examples are better. I would be very thankfull for both

Thanks for anybody's help.

Comment: There are examples of how to start another process everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute another program in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244439/execute-another-program-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

It is explained quite detailed.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute` are both viable approaches.