# Avoid unsafe function like system()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a simple piece of C++ code that is running on Windows:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    QString command = "cd " + userinputpath.toLatin1();
    if (system(command.toLatin1())==0)
    {std::cout<< "Executed Successfully"}
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that using the `system()` function is prone to injection attacks. Beside using `system()`, is there any other alternatives to not using `system()` for Windows? I saw many solutions which use `exec()`, `fork()`, etc. However, they only work for Unix systems. Is there any solution for Windows?

Comment: Since you are using `Qt` use `QProcess`

Comment: The `system` function starts a new "shell" (command line interpreter), as a brand new and unrelated process. All commands executed by `system` will be local to that shell, and only that shell. So a command like `cd` will change the directory for that shell, and the change will be lost once the shell exits and the `system` function returns. It will *not* change the working directory for your process. This is true for any framework or function that creates new independent processes.

Comment: In most cases it's best to figure out how to do what you want directly inside your existing process, rather than spawning a child process (by any method).  For example, if you are trying to change the current directory of your process, then you can do that by calling the _chdir() function (as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir?view=msvc-170 )

Comment: `cd` only makes sense in a shell (and has no side effects on the process starting the shell). So anything like `exec` wouldn't work here either. `cd` is not an executable. I'd suggest you use a better example use case.

Comment: Perhaps you want [std::filesystem::current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, `cd` is just an example of the command line. A more detailed example would be exporting/importing a database table `"psql.exe" --username "admin" --no-password --dbname "mydb" <"path to backup file"` in the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new process in C++ code under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876266/how-to-create-a-new-process-in-c-code-under-windows)

Comment: in such case why can't the user run this directly in shell, and you are being a middle man with C++ app?

If you want to avoid system() for safety reasons, you should avoid also all possible workarounds (which would enable user to run shell-like command, ie. loading psql.exe excutable with custom arguments), so you just shouldn't provide this functionality.

If you want to provide functionality like this and also be somewhat secure, you need to heavily limit available commands and arguments, ie. whitelist executables to run, parse arguments, sanitize them, build command yourself..

Comment: In short, the truly unsafe part of the code in your question is `userinputpath.toLatin1()` and how the result is used. The `system` alone is as safe as its arguments, not inherently unsafe just because of itself. So you need to solve security of the user input, if that's hardened enough, keep using system if it works for you. Workaround will not improve security in any means, if you end up running user input any way.

Comment: In the windows API, there is `CreateProcess()` and related functions.  They give a more granular control over how a process is launched to run a program than `system()` does and don't generally do that via a command processor.   However, any approach to create a process to run a second program involves vulnerabilities (e.g. ability to substitute an unintended program to be executed) compared with finding some way to achieve the same effect within your program

Comment: You may also consider using ShellExecuteEx. Make sure only trusted programs and commands are allowed to execute and check commands.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use the CreateProcess() function to execute external commands in a more controlled and secure manner. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // ...
    
    QString userinputpath = "your_input_path_here"; // Assuming you have your input path
    
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    
    // Construct the command line string
    QString command = "cmd /c cd " + userinputpath;
    
    // Convert QString to wchar_t*
    wchar_t* commandW = new wchar_t[command.length() + 1];
    command.toWCharArray(commandW);
    commandW[command.length()] = L'\0';
    
    // Create the process
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, commandW, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << "Executed Successfully" << std::endl;
        
        // Close process and thread handles.
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error executing command" << std::endl;
    }
    
    delete[] commandW;
    
    return 0;
}
```

we're using the CreateProcess() function to execute the command in a secure manner. The command is constructed as "cmd /c cd path" to ensure proper handling of the command and arguments. Additionally, the input path is converted to a wide-character string (wchar_t*) to match the expected input format of CreateProcess().

Replace "your_input_path_here" with the actual input path you want to use. Also, error handling and memory management should be further enhanced based on your application's needs.

Comment: How is this more secure? If the user input is untrusted, what prevents them from supplying something like `c:\ & del *.*`