# How to execute another exe from a C++ program in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I want my C++ program to execute another .exe, in Windows. How would I do this? I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned int input;
    cout << "Enter 1 to execute program." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input == 1) /*execute program here*/;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c to call any executable from yours.

Comment: You can use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx) for this.

Comment: This works: ```system("programtoexecutenamehere")```

Comment: possible duplicate [Execute another program in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244439/execute-another-program-in-c)

Comment: you can use Google search!

Comment: I did use google search and found an answer that worked for Unix but not windows. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use the `system` function

```
int result = system("C:\\Program Files\\Program.exe");
```

Comment: Can we also pass parameters to that program?

Answer (score 35):

This is a solution I found when looking for an answer previously.
It stated that you should always avoid using system() because:

- It is resource heavy
- It defeats security -- you don't know you it's a valid command or does the same thing on every system, you could even start up programs you didn't intend to start up. The danger is that when you directly execute a program, it gets the same privileges as your program -- meaning that if, for example, you are running as system administrator then the malicious program you just inadvertently executed is also running as system administrator.
- Anti virus programs hate it, your program could get flagged as a virus.

Instead CreateProcess() can be used.
 Createprocess() is used to just start up an .exe and creating a new process for it. The application will run independent from the calling application.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void startup(LPCSTR lpApplicationName)
{
    // additional information
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // start the program up
    CreateProcessA
    (
        lpApplicationName,   // the path
        argv[1],                // Command line
        NULL,                   // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,                   // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,                  // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,     // Opens file in a separate console
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    );
        // Close process and thread handles. 
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Comment: sometimes 'argv' variable may be out of scope. I have usually just assigned another global variable the value of argv and used it instead

Answer (score 12):

Use the CreateProcess() Function.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for details

Answer (score 5):

You can make a call using `system`

```
system("./some_command")
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this answer should work with different programs, I tested it with Chrome.

```
// open program.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string command = "start chrome https://www.google.com/";
    system(command.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```