# How to run different project files from one project? (Visual Studio, C++)

Tags: c++, project, group

I am trying to make a school project, which doesn't have to be like this, but I think it will impress my teacher.

We are a group of 5 people, with 5 different projects, and I was wondering if it's possible to run all our projects from a singular project.

For example, if the program asks me `"which project?"` I type in `"5"` and runs the fifth project and so on for the rest.

I was just really curious if it's possible.

Comment: If you still want to be able to run these executables separately, then you'd probably want to write something like `if (input == "5") system("path/to/other/executable");`.

Comment: When you say "run different project files", do you mean have it run different applications (.exe) when you hit the "Run" button?  Do you mean have Visual studio load different C++ project files (.vcxproj)?  Something else?

Comment: It's also possible to have multiple executables in a single solution and switch between them with "Set startup item"

Comment: @Joe i want to get the source code from my classmates, put it in a project in visual studio (because some of them use code blocks), and have a separate project from which i run all their projects, hope it made sense

Comment: @Genjutsu i would prefer something thats done within the code, that i type in the console "5" and runs the fifth project

Comment: You have to move their code into separate libraries and link your executable to these libraries.

Comment: That's essentially what a *solution* is in Visual Studio.  It is one collection of multiple projects.   Each solution has a single current "startup project" that runs when you Debug.

Comment: @Genjutsu how would i go about doing that? what do i need to search for

Comment: @Joe i was looking for something that i could write in the code, so i can run a project from the solution within the console, that would open like a new console or something similar to that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703721/how-to-execute-another-exe-from-a-c-program-in-windows) is sort of what i want to do