# Execute a "Run" command in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7

On Windows 7, I can hit Start then type "run" and it will give me the windows classic run dialog, in which I can type various programs and commands.

If I wanted to perform a Run action using a C++ program, how would I go about doing that?

Ex:  If I open the Run dialog and type "mspaint", it opens Paint.  How could I use C++ to run "mspaint" and get the same results as the Run dialog itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute another program in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244439/execute-another-program-in-c)

Comment: @mah is it the same thing?  Run can do things besides open programs, yes?

Comment: ShellExecute() should do this.

Comment: @jros What other things are you looking to do? If it's not a program, it's probably something that can be done by using arguments sent to the cmd program.

Comment: @mah Every time I start up my work computer I have to run 'smc -stop' to kill an annoying process.  I'm not sure exactly what this does, but I was hoping to create a simple program that I would set to automatically run on start up, it would execute this Run command, then finish.

Comment: @jros if you open a cmd shell are you able to do that? if so, simply create a .bat file that does it and runs on startup. No programming necessary. There is another stack exchange site that would be more appropriate for you to ask "how do I automatically 'smc -stop' at bootup?" but I'm not sure which site; perhaps http://superuser.com/

Comment: @jros: you can use a batch file or a shortcut, no need to create a C++ program for it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::system("program call");` is one way to go in case you don't need to interact with the process of the opened program.

`system()` returns the return value of the called program.

Answer (score 0):

First, a handy shortcut: rather than having to type "run" into the start menu, you can use Windows+R (hold down the Windows key and press R).

Second, [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) will work, but [system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) on Windows does in fact work on non-program files, and it's certainly simpler to use than ShellExecute, unless you need something specific like running an application minimized.

The only caveat is that system() cannot be called by a Windows application. It can only be called from a console app.