# change Windows 7 tablet PC settings using code.

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, touch, registry

I am designing a touch driver for windows 7 .
 Windows 7 has a mechanism to associate your touch screen with a particular display, see "Tablet PC Settings"->Configure .

What i want to do is ,change the tablet pc settings using c/c++ so that i am able to change if the input goes to primary monitor or secondary monitor . Is there any way in which we can change the settings using C/C++ are they stored in registry somewhere or somewhere else ? . If yes , how can i modify it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429738/detecting-installed-programs-via-registry).Once you detect you have to just check the installMode.If install its value would 1 otherwise 0.

There is a list of [Registry function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you can use in c++.

The touch screen registry stores information necessary to configure the behavior of the touch screen.

The **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\DeviceMap\Touch** registry key is required to configure the touch screen. The following table shows the named values for the Touch configuration parameters.

For Info See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924827.aspx)

Comment: Ohk thanks :), That's partially my answer . I also want to know where are the registry settings which tell which monitor is associate with touch screen . I am not able to find them using regedit .