# How to make the 'open with' dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I  made a program to search for .txt files.

If I click a file it means that the "open with" dialog box should appear, and that dialog box will contain a list of all installed programs.

I am using this code for searching through the files:

```
  public File[] finder( String dirName)
  {
      // Create a file object on the directory.
      File dir = new File(dirName);
      // Return a list of all files in the directory.
      return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter();
  } 

  public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
  { 
      return filename.endsWith(".txt");
  }
```

What Java code can I use to make the "open with" dialog box appear?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This is the first result in Google: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser Filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517770/jfilechooser-filters)

Comment: Check my edit. After some careful reading I think this is what OP wants.

Comment: i dont want file chooser.. I need that Dialog box contain only installed program in the os..

Comment: @user2364985 u have to implement it by yourself . see my answer i provided links for doing such on windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use  [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for this. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html):

```
//Create a file chooser
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
...
//In response to a button click:
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //This is where a real application would open the file.
            log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        } else {
            log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
   } ...
}
```

Comment: i dont want file chooser.. I need that Dialog box contain only installed program in the os

Comment: @user2364985 You can configure your FileChooser with ExtensionFilter:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html

Answer (score 3):

> What Java code can I use to make the "open with" dialog box appear?

To my knowledge, there is nothing in the J2SE like that.  OTOH the [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API can open a `File` in whatever app. is the **default** consumer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own dialog for that purpose .And for coming how to get program list .on windows you can use registry . see this link [Detecting installed programs via registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429738/detecting-installed-programs-via-registry)

and also check how to acces registry via java 
[read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)