# how to create an open with dialog in java which displays the list of only the text editors present in the system?

Tags: java, text-editor, open-with

[image] i need to open text files in my java program, in the text editor based on user selection, something similar to the windows open-with dialog.
How can it be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542359/how-to-make-the-open-with-dialog-box