# Right click and "Open with..."

Tags: java, javafx, open-with

I have an image displayed with an ImageView. When I perform a right click on it, 
I want to be able to choose a program to open the image with (ie. have an "Open With" menu item like on Windows). I know the solution to open the image with the default associated program and I know how to handle right clicking but I found nothing about the "Open With" menu action.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?  Could you just list a bunch of programs and ask the user to choose one?  Then use `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: I want to open the "Open With" window ([link](http://cdn.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Open-with.jpg)) to let the user choose a program from its computer to open or edit the image.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542359/how-to-make-the-open-with-dialog-box

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I manage to do it with `Runtime.exec()`. The shell command is just `openwith` so this do the trick : 
    `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("openwith " + file.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: [ContextMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html)?