# How do I list all the installed applications using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, automation

is there any way to list all the installed application (including MS office applications) in windows OS using python...?

I expect the output as list of applications:

```
Telegram
Brave
Whatsapp
MS word
& all the applications installed...
```

Comment: The information can easily be looked up in the registry.

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/429738

Answer (score 1):

There's a python package specifically for that task: https://pypi.org/project/windows-tools.installed-software/

You can install the package by executing `pip install windows_tools.installed_software` in your terminal and then you just have to import the `get_installed_software` function and call it accordingly, like so:

```py
from windows_tools.installed_software import get_installed_software

for software in get_installed_software():
    print(software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher'])
```

Comment: This is a link only answer, you should edit and explain how to use the package in relation to what OP is asking.

Comment: @user56700 the usage seemed trivial so I skipped it but I added it nonetheless. That being said, isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132434/list-of-installed-programs anyways?

Comment: You could try to install `pip install windows-tools`, and this should let you continue.

Answer (score 0):

As @ekhumoro commented, you can get it from the windows registry. Using python you can try something like this:

```
import winreg

reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
key = winreg.OpenKey(reg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
    software_key_name = winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
    software_key = winreg.OpenKey(key, software_key_name)
    try:
        software_name = winreg.QueryValueEx(software_key, "DisplayName")[0]
        print(software_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```